# Webform sending emails when submission is created and completed - duplicate emails

Tags: webforms, emails

We have a webform set to email both a notification and a confirmation after a user submits. Under ADDITIONAL SETTTINGS, Send email, only "When submission is completed" is selected for both. Two (duplicate) emails go out for each notification and confirmation. In the logs it says the emails are sent **after the submission is created** and then **again after the submission is completed**.

My question is, what can I do to to reduce the emails down to one each for notification and confirmation? I am guessing I have the settings incorrect. Hope this makes sense.

Using Drupal 9 and Webform version 6.2.2
The form was created with the Contact Us template.

Thank you.